# AsyncTask limits buffers size?

Tags: android, string, buffer, android-asynctask, http-get

I'm trying to get html content. Everything works in AsyncTask thread. This is my code:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {         
        InputStream content = null;
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);                                        
            content = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }                       
        if (content == null) {
            return "Error";
        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try {
            while (((line = in.readLine()) != null)) {
                Log.i("DEBUG", line);
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            Log.i("DEBUG2", sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();           
}
```

Problem is, that I get only part of response. The first debug shows, that while loop sees all content, but the second debug, which shows info from StringBuffer, shows only part of content. So, there are any limits for using StringBuffer in AsyncTask?

I tried to use EntitiyUtils, but got same problem:

```
return new String(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

Any solutions, tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);       
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        return responseHandler.handleResponse(response);           
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem was logcat. It truncated the logmessages (see comments)

Comment: Same problem, I got exactly same amount information like before.

Comment: Try to put the string into a textfield. The string is probably truncated in logcat.

Comment: Yes, logcat truncated, so I confused too much about this. Yours solutions are good!